# constructor initialization in c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm a programming student but my professor refuses to explain anything, in this assignment she introduced classes and I'm struggling to understand the constructor concept/syntax. I have a "matching constructor" error on two lines of my code (I've marked them with comments, the problem lines of code are both in main.) The code is a bank account sim, it takes withdrawals, deposits, and calculates the interest rate on the account. Can anyone explain what the problem is?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include "SavingsAcc.h"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  
  //savings account information
  SavingsAccount savAcc, *savingsAcc = &savAcc;//savAcc CONSTRUCTOR ERROR "no matching constructor for initialization of SavingsAccount"

  savAcc.setAccNum(1234);
  savAcc.setAccBal(322.75);
  savAcc.setNumWithdrawal(2);
  savAcc.setNumDep(3);
  savAcc.setAnnIntRate(0.06);
  savAcc.setMonthServCharg(2.50);

  //misc declarations
  int option; 
  
  do
  {
    cout << "Logged in successfully...\nSAVINGS ACCOUNT\n1. Desposit\n2. Withdraw\n3. Logout\nEnter option: " << endl;
    cin >> option;
  
    switch (option)
    {

    case 1:

    SavingsAccount savAccObj; //CONSTRUCTOR ERROR "no matching constructor for initialization of SavingsAccount"

    savAccObj.deposit;
    
    case 2:

    savAccObj.withdraw;
    }

  }
  while (option != 3);
}
```

Account.cpp

```
#include "Account.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


Account::Account(){};//constructor


//overloaded constructor
Account::Account(double accBal, double annIntRate){
  accBal = accBal;
  annIntRate = 0;
};

//deposit base class function
int Account::deposit(double accBal, int numDepos)
{
  double depos;
  cout << "Enter deposit: "<< endl;
  cin >> depos;
  accBal += depos;
  numDepos ++;
  return accBal;
}

//withdraw base class function
void Account::withdraw(double accBal, int numWithdrawal)
{
  double amount; 
  cin >> amount;
  accBal -= amount;
  numWithdrawal ++; 
}

//interest rate calculation
void Account::calcInt(double accBal, double annIntRate)
{
  double monthlyIntRate = annIntRate/2;
  double monthlyInt = accBal * monthlyIntRate;
  accBal += monthlyInt;

}
```

Account.h

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

class Account
{
  //variable declarations
  private:
  
  int accNum;
  double accBal;
  int numWithdrawal;
  int numDepos;
  double annIntRate;
  double monthServCharg;
  
  public:

  Account();

  Account(double, double); //overloaded constructor
  
  virtual int deposit(double, int); //base class deposit declaration 
  
  virtual void withdraw(double, int); //base class withdraw declaration
  
  virtual void calcInt(double, double); //updates interest rate
  
  void setAccNum(int); //setter
  int getAccNum(){return accNum;} //getter

  void setAccBal(double);//setter
  double getAccBal(){return accBal;}//getter

  void setNumWithdrawal(int);//setter
  int getNumWithdrawal(){return numWithdrawal;}//getter

  void setNumDep(int);//setter
  int getNumDep(){return numDepos;}//getter

  void setAnnIntRate(double);//setter
  double getAnnIntRate(){return annIntRate;}//getter

  void setMonthServCharg(double); //setter
  double getMonthServCharg(){return monthServCharg;}//getter
};
#endif
```

SavingsAcc.cpp

```
#include "SavingsAcc.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//status constructor
SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(bool status)
{
  status = false;
}

//deposit money function
void SavingsAccount::deposit(bool status, double accBal, int numDepos) 
{
  Account obj;
  obj.deposit(accBal,0);

  if (accBal > 25.00)
  status = true;
  else 
  status = false;
}

//withdraw money child function, updates account status, service charges, interest rate etc
void SavingsAccount::withdraw(double accBal, int numWithdrawal, double annIntRate, double monthServCharg) 
{
  double amount;
  if (accBal <= 25.00)
  cout << "Balance too low, withdrawals cannot be made at this time"<<endl;
  else
  {
    do
    { 
      Account obj;
      obj.withdraw(numWithdrawal, 0); // parent deposit function
      
      if (numWithdrawal > 4)
      monthServCharg += 1;

      if (accBal < 25.00)
      {annIntRate += 0.01;}
    }
    while (amount > accBal);
    cout << "Insufficient funds!";
  }
   
}

//outputs the report of account 
void SavingsAccount::accountReport(int accNum, bool status, int numWithdrawal, int numDepos, double monthServeCharg, double accBal)
{
  
  cout << "====ACCOUNT STATUS===="<<endl;
  cout << "Account number: "<< accNum <<endl;
  
  if (status == true) //status 
  cout << "Satus: Active" << endl;
  else 
  cout <<"Status: Inactive" << endl;

  cout << "Total deposits: "<< numDepos << endl;
  cout << "Total withdrawals" << numWithdrawal << endl;
  cout << "Service charges: "<< monthServeCharg << endl;
  cout << "Balance: "<<accBal<<endl;

}
```

SavingsAcc.h

```
    #ifndef SAVINGSACC_H
#define SAVINGSACC_H
#include <iostream>

class SavingsAccount: public Account
{
  private:
   
    bool status; //status variable
  
  public:

  SavingsAccount(bool); // constuctor
  
  void deposit(bool, double, int); // deposit function
  
  void withdraw(double, int, double, double); //withdraw function

  void accountReport(int, bool, int, int, double, double ); // full report of account
};
#endif
```

Comment: If you want `SavingsAccount savAccObj;` to work, you need to provide a zero argument constructor for `SavingsAccount`.

Answer (score 1):

The construcor for `SavingsAccount` takes a `bool` as input, but you are not passing in a `bool` value when creating your `savAcc` and `savAccObj` objects.